# How do i copy a URL from searchbar?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, discord

I wrote a program that automatically navigates me threw a website, but how do I copy my current URL.

Context: I am attempting to code a watch2gether bot that automatically creates a watch2gether room

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _...URL from searchbar..._?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which programming language you use, but in Python3 its simply `driver.current_url`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this would work:

```
url = driver.current_url
```

See documentation here:
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=url